# HttpServletRequest field may not be static, final or have an Annotation type error with jersey 2

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have the following class for REST calls. Before I was using jersey 1.13 on which everything was working fine, now I have upgraded to jersey 2.27, I am getting the following error on any rest call to the given class

> WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4]
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.logErrors The following warnings
>   have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for
>   [com.MyClass] with an exception: MultiException stack 1 of 2
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field field(HttpServletRequest
>   request in com..MyClass) may not be static, final or have an
>   Annotation type
>
> MultiException stack 2 of 2 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors
>   were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
>     implementation=com.MyClass  contracts={com.MyClass}
>     scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
>     qualifiers={}   descriptorType=CLASS    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
>     metadata=   rank=0  loader=null     proxiable=null
>     proxyForSameScope=null  analysisName=null   id=150  locatorId=0
>     identityHashCode=1270899559     reified=false)

```
@Path("/myclass")
public MyClass{
@Context
    static
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Context
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/method1")
    public Response method1(PostObj postObj) {
        //implementation
   }

}
```

If I remove static keyword it works fine. But I want request to be kept static only. What is the issue with static keyword here ? How do I fix it ?

Comment: Why you need request to be static? every request is different than the other

Comment: _Why_ do you want it static? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to _me_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JAX-RS API from the Java EE ecosystem of technologies provides the annotation `@Context`, to inject 12 object instances related to the context of HTTP requests. It behaves just like the `@Inject` and `@Autowired` annotations in Java EE and Spring respectively.

The object instances that it can inject are the following:

- `SecurityContext` – Security context instance for the current HTTP request
- `Request` – Used for setting precondition request processing
- `Application`, `Configuration`, and Providers - Provide access to the JAX-RS 
  application, configuration, and providers instances
- `ResourceContext` – Resource context class instances
- `ServletConfig` – The ServletConfig instance instance
- `ServletContext` – The ServletContext instance
- `HttpServletRequest` – The HttpServletRequest instance for the current request
- `HttpServletResponse` – The HttpServletResponse instance for the current request
- `HttpHeaders` – Maintains the HTTP header keys and values
- `UriInfo` – Query parameters and path variables from the URI called

And here’s an example of injection into an instances field:

```
@Path("/")
public class EndpointResource {
    @Context
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getHeaders(){
        // Code here that uses httpHeaders
    }
}
```

Read up on injection, there is a reason why you can't inject static fields. Avoiding dependency injection on static fields and methods is a good practice, as it has the following restrictions and can be hard to debug.

1. Static fields will be injected after the first object of the class was created via DI, which means no access to the static field in the constructor
2. Static fields can not be marked as final, otherwise the compiler or the application complains at runtime about them
3. Static methods are called only once after the first instance of the class was created

Comment: So u meant to say removing the static keyword is the right thing to do ? jersey1 was ignoring this ?

Comment: Yes, the proper thing to do here is to remove the static keyword.